# ListBox web control attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

The Windows Forms "edition" of a ListBox has an attribute called `ScrollAlwaysVisible`. It removes the scroll-bar from the control easily.

Is there something I can to do achieve the same in the asp control for webforms? I am setting the line count of the box to the same as a list data, therefore have no need for the scroll-bar. It looks terribly ugly.

*Setting the rows of the listbox, by request:*

```
List<string> boxList = new List<string>()
ListBox<string> newBox = new ListBox<string>();
void someVoid()
{
    int count = boxList.Count;
    ListBox.Rows = count;
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the line count? It works for me if I simply add listBox.Rows = 9; (having 6 items in the listobx).

Comment: @Uporabnik003 Added some pseudo-code as an example. There may be some discrepancy with the formation of the listbox here, but all else works (only when more than two rows of data is added to the list, otherwise listbox retains its default appearance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `css` to make scrollbar always visible, like this.

`<asp:ListBox ID="lst" runat="server" style="overflow-y:visible;"></asp:ListBox>`

Note: this will display vertical scroll bar always, if you want to have both horizontal and vertical then use `overflow:visible`.

Comment: I take it `overflow:invisible` will achieve what I was after?

Comment: No, it should be `overflow:hidden`, possible values - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp